# Ubuntu packages out of date for libv8

Tags: apt

I found these packages out of date and was wondering if there was a way to update the repo?

```
libv8-3.14-dbg/xenial 3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2 amd64
libv8-3.14-dev/xenial 3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2 amd64
libv8-3.14.5/xenial,now 3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2 amd64 [residual-config]
libv8-dev/xenial 3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2 amd64
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Yes sir. Had to build from scratch.